# Truncate string after the last occurrence of '- ' or '|'

Tags: regex, postgresql, regex-lookarounds

I'm using Postgres and would like to remove everything after the last occurrence of '- ' or '|'. this is the query I came up with:

```
select regexp_replace( title, E'(- |\\|).+$', '') as title from articles
```

The problem is that a string like:

```
'Trump tweets in China - how, and why does it matter? - BBC News'
```

is truncated too early:

```
'Trump tweets in China'
```

How can I make it remove the suffix only after the last occurrence of '- '?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `E'(?:(?! - |\\|).)+$'`

Comment: Thank. now if I don't have any '- ' or '|' it returns empty string, how can I correct it

Comment: You just need to put that before - `E'(- |\\|)(?:(?!- |\\|).)+$'` and replace with `\1`. Or `E'(- |\\|)(?:(?!\\1).)+$'`

Comment: Wiktor - you are "THE MAN!" how can I mark it as the right answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match either a space and a hyphen or a pipe symobl, capture them, and then just match the rest of the string that is not equal to the captured text:

```
(- |\|)(?:(?!\1).)+$
```

Replace with `\1`. Escape as necessary (you need to use double escapes in `E'...'` strings).

**Details**

- `(- |\|)` - either a `-`  or a `|` symbol
- `(?:(?!\1).)+` - any char (`.`), 1 or more occurrences (`+`), that does not start a `-`  sequence or not equal to `|` - depending on what was captured into Group 1.
- `$` - end of string.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/CpOBsx/1).

Answer (score 4):

You could try this:

```
select regexp_replace ('Trump tweets in China - how, and why does it matter? - BBC News',
    '[|-][^|-]*$', '')
```

It's basically saying:

- a `|` or a `-`
- followed by any number of characters that are neither a `|` nor a `-` at the end of the string

Result:

```
Trump tweets in China - how, and why does it matter?
```